# Enable Cross-Origin XMLHttpRequest in devtool

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest, google-chrome-devtools

I'm working on a devtool Chrome extension and would like to log all XHR request of the current website. So in my injected script ea `"messageback-script"` I have this:

```
(function(open) {
  XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(method, url, async) {


console.log('The URL is: ' + url); 


  };

})(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open);
```

And I have given required permissions in the `manifest.json`:

```
{
    "name": "DevToolsPanel",
    "version": "0.1",
    "description": "Log XHR requests",
    "devtools_page": "devtools.html",
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "background.js"
        ]
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs", 
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
    ],
    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

The problem is that I don't see anything in the console log (blank). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Building a Chrome Extension - Inject code in a page using a Content script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script)

Comment: Comment: it's not an exact duplicate, but it's the canonical question for your problem.

Comment: @Xan Thanks but the answer only talks about code injection. Do you think that is the problem? Because I injected a lot of code and it all works as expected that's why I think the problem maybe something else.

Comment: Why close, please elaborate or bug off

Comment: @Xan It's plain rude trying to close a perfectly good question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59873/discussion-between-xan-and-youss).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having examined [the code you are using](https://github.com/thingsinjars/devtools-extension/), I can say that this script is evaluated via `chrome.tabs.executeScript`, making it a Content Script.

Content Scripts live in an [isolated context](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment), and as such modifying the XHR prototype only affects XHR in your content script(s). There's a [canonical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script) describing this problem and workarounds.

However, since you're writing a devtools extension, you have a simpler solution via [`chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_inspectedWindow#method-eval), which directly executes code in the page's own context.

```
// In the devtool panel code
chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval("/* Your code here*/");
```

Comment: Can you help out on how and where to put this. So far I have this in the devtool panel.js: `document.querySelector('#insert').addEventListener('click', function() { 
sendObjectToInspectedPage({action: "script", content: "jquery.js"});
sendObjectToInspectedPage({action: "script", content: "messageback-script.js"});
}, false);` What Im saying is that there is nowhere a place to put that code...

Comment: By code I mean literal code in your question, as a string.

Comment: Instead of your `sendObjectToInspectedPage`?

Comment: That doesn't work: `document.querySelector('#insert').addEventListener('click', function() { 
chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval("console.log('hello world')");
}, false);` And you wanted to close my question...;-)